onnxruntime error while using uv python package
I am using a uv on my project. It was working all fine before but from yesterday it is throwing error like this when ever i do uv sync. It does make virtual env but when ever i try to add other packages it says
Resolved 147 packages in 0.50ms
error: Distribution `onnxruntime==1.19.2 @ registry+https://pypi.org/simple` can't be installed because it doesn't have a source distribution or wheel for the current platform

I thought i made some mistake on my machine so i tried even on other fresh machines and even servers too but same error. I also tried installing onnxruntime==1.19.2 but it doesn't work.

What is your platform and Python version?

With so little details, I can only suggests to delete .venv folder and uv.lock, then retry launching uv sync.
